# Что такое Connection?

Tags: java, база-данных, jdbc, connection

У меня на собеседовании спросили, что такое Connection. Я ответил, что это соединение к БД и рассказал как его получить `DriverManager.getConnection(MYSQL_URL, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD)` И в фитбэке мне написали, **"плохо представляет, что это"**. Помогите мне понять что такое Connection.

**UPDATE:**
То есть что можно ответить на этот вопрос кроме того, что это сессия между БД и приложение и с помощью него можно отправлять SQL-запросы и т.п.?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html ?

Comment: Я читал документацию. Просто не понял, что значит 'представлять что такое Connection'. То есть что можно ответить на этот вопрос кроме того, что это сессия между БД и приложение и с помощью него можно отправлять SQL-запросы и т.п.?

Comment: А вопрос был другой.

Comment: Наверное от вас хотели услышать, что это объект (интерфейс) с такими-то методами

Comment: Какая ещё сессия, нельзя так выражаться, потому что это неверно.

Comment: первое предложение в документации 'A connection (session) with a specific database')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [тут](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) даётся понимание откуда берется Connection, что это такое, и как его едят.

> JDBC API содержит два основных типа интерфейсов: первый – для разработчиков приложений и второй (более низкого уровня) – для разработчиков драйверов.
>
> Соединение с базой данных описывается классом, реализующим интерфейс `java.sql.Connection`. Имея соединение с базой данных, можно создавать объекты типа `Statement`, служащие для исполнения запросов к базе данных на языке SQL.

<sub>Следует знать JDBC API предоставляет *только* интерфейсы для использования. Потому, что реализация у каждой базы данных разная.</sub>